# mysql how to merge /join/complete information from 1 rows to other row from the same table

Tags: mysql, join, merge

I have a table like this

```
ID   | starttime | endtime  |manualid
1    | 12:24:00  | 13:25:00 |null
2    | null      | null     |1
3    | null      | null     |5
4    | 16:34:00  | 19:25:00 |null
5    | 21:40:00  | 23:25:00 |null
```

What I want is when I make a `SELECT` have something like this

```
ID   | starttime | endtime  |searchid
1    | 12:24:00  | 13:25:00 |null
2    | 12:24:00  | 13:25:00 |1
3    | 21:40:00  | 23:25:00 |5
4    | 16:34:00  | 19:25:00 |null
5    | 21:40:00  | 23:25:00 |null
```

The idea is to complete the information of some rows with the information from the same table from other rows using their id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i'm trying to join your_table with itself, on `manualid = id`. If the join does not succeed (because `manualid is null`, or it has an id that does not exist) `t2.id` will be null.

I'm selecting `starttime` and `endtime` from the original row if the join does not succeed, otherwise i'm selecting it from the other row:

```
SELECT
  t1.ID,
  case when t2.id is null then t1.starttime else t2.starttime end as starttime,
  case when t2.id is null then t1.endtime else t2.endtime end as endtime,
  t1.manualid
FROM
  your_table t1 left join your_table t2 on t1.manualid=t2.id
```